# Wie kann man richtig nach der zuständigen Person fragen?

Tags: phrase-request, standard-german

Manchmal wenn ich eine E-Mail schreibe (oder jemanden etwas frage), um eine Information zu bekommen oder um meine Sachen erledigen zu lassen, bin ich mir nicht ganz sicher, ob ich mit der richtigen Person spreche.

Wie soll man in so einem Fall fragen, ob man mit der zuständigen Person spricht? Und falls die Person nicht richtig ist, wie kann man nach der zuständigen Person fragen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Sind Sie dafür zuständig?

oder etwas informeller

> Bin ich da bei Ihnen richtig / an der richtigen Adresse?

Nach der tatsächlich zuständigen Person kannst Du z.B. so fragen:

> Wer ist dafür zuständig?
>   An wen kann / soll ich mich wenden?

Answer (score 5):

Normalerweise schildere ich zunächst mein Anliegen und schreibe ich dann so etwas wie:

> Falls Sie in diesem Fall/hierfür nicht zuständig sein sollten, nennen Sie mir bitte den richtigen Ansprechpartner.

Alternativ

> Falls Sie in diesem Fall/hierfür nicht zuständig sein sollten, teilen Sie mir bitte mit, an wen ich mich wenden kann.

Comment: Danke sehr für Deine Antwort aber leider kann ich nicht zwei Antworten als Solution markieren aber bestimmt werde ich Deine Empfehlungen gebrauchen +1.

Comment: Kein Problem :-) Gefühlt sind Matthias' Antworten ein bisschen weniger formell als meine, so dass Du für jeden Kontext auswählen kannst :-)

Comment: Ich hoffe, ich finde immer die richtige Person, um nicht ständig nach einer Person suchen aber falls ich brauche, habe ich jetzt viele Optionen :)